# Clarification about flatten function in Theano

Tags: numpy, theano, flatten, conv-neural-network

in [http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html#lenet] it says:

```
This will generate a matrix of shape (batch_size, nkerns[1] * 4 * 4),
# or (500, 50 * 4 * 4) = (500, 800) with the default values.
layer2_input = layer1.output.flatten(2)
```

when I use flatten function on a numpy 3d array I get a 1D array. but here it says I get a matrix. How does flatten(2) work in theano?

A similar example on numpy produces 1D array:

```
     a= array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6],
    [ 7,  8,  9]],

   [[10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18]],

   [[19, 20, 21],
    [22, 23, 24],
    [25, 26, 27]]])

   a.flatten(2)=array([ 1, 10, 19,  4, 13, 22,  7, 16, 25,  2, 11, 20,  5, 14, 23,  8, 17,
   26,  3, 12, 21,  6, 15, 24,  9, 18, 27])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

numpy doesn't support flattening only some dimensions but Theano does.

So if `a` is a numpy array, `a.flatten(2)` doesn't make any sense. It runs without error but only because the `2` is passed as the `order` parameter which seems to cause numpy to stick with the default order of `C`.

Theano's `flatten` *does* support axis specification. [The documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.flatten) explains how it works.

```
Parameters:
    x (any TensorVariable (or compatible)) – variable to be flattened
    outdim (int) – the number of dimensions in the returned variable

Return type:
    variable with same dtype as x and outdim dimensions

Returns:
    variable with the same shape as x in the leading outdim-1 dimensions,
    but with all remaining dimensions of x collapsed into the last dimension.
```

> For example, if we flatten a tensor of shape (2, 3, 4, 5) with
>   flatten(x, outdim=2), then we’ll have the same (2-1=1) leading
>   dimensions (2,), and the remaining dimensions are collapsed. So the
>   output in this example would have shape (2, 60).

A simple Theano demonstration:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt


def compile():
    x = tt.tensor3()
    return theano.function([x], x.flatten(2))


def main():
    a = numpy.arange(2 * 3 * 4).reshape((2, 3, 4))
    f = compile()
    print a.shape, f(a).shape


main()
```

prints

```
(2L, 3L, 4L) (2L, 12L)
```

Comment: the code gave errors. my version of ur code(for newbies like me) :                    `import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
from numpy import dtype


x = tt.tensor4()
f=theano.function([x], x.flatten(2))

a = np.asarray(np.arange(2 * 3 * 4*5).reshape((2, 3, 4, 5)),dtype=theano.config.floatX)
print a 
print f(a) `

Comment: What is the error? It may be better to start a new question if you've already searched but been unable to find an existing answer.